# a question on profinite group

Tags: group-theory

Assume that a profinite group $G$ is generated by $X$ as abstract group. Here $X$ is assumed to be a closed subset of $G$ such that $X=X^{-1}$ and $1\in X$. 
For each $n$ let $X_n$ be the set of all finite products $x_1^{\pm 1}\cdots x_{n}^{\pm 1}$ where $x_1,\cdots, x_n\in X$. It is clear that
$$G=\bigcup_{n=1}^nX_n$$

> How to prove that each $X_n$ is closed in $G$?

I think that it should be simple but I have not got an answer yet.

Thankssssss.

Comment: So you're saying $\,\langle X\rangle=G\,$ (as abstract groups) , yet you *require* from $\,X\,$ to closed (in the profinite topology, I pressume...?) and contain the unit...why? Such is the exercise or you think that *it must be* so?

Comment: Well, I assume here that $X$ is an symmetric set which contains the unit element. Oh, maybe I should edit the expression of elements in $X_n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $X_n$, for $n > 1$, is the product of $X$, which is closed by assumption, and $X_{n-1}$, which we may assume to be closed by induction. (Here as usual the product of two subsets $A$ and $B$ of a group is the set $\{ a b : a \in A, b \in B\}$.)

Now in a topological group the product of two closed subsets need not be closed. [A nice example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124130/sum-of-two-closed-sets-in-mathbb-r-is-closed) is the sum of the subgroups $\mathbf{Z}$ and  $\sqrt{2} \, \mathbf{Z}$ of $\mathbf{R}$.

But [if one of the two subsets is compact, then the product is closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71983/product-of-compact-and-closed-in-topological-group-is-closed).

Since a profinite group is compact, its closed subsets are compact, and we are done.

Comment: Thanks alot for pointing out this for me.

Comment: @9999, you're very welcome!